# Как проще всего оформить меню?

Tags: html, вёрстка, css

Здравствуйте. Скажите, пожалуйста, как проще всего оформить горизонтальное меню. В принципе само меню готово, но есть одно маленькое но. Как видно на скрине, там есть два пункта: корзина и вход/регистрация пользователя.

При добавлении товара в корзину - цена увеличивается в длину и одна рамка наезжает на другую (то же самое и при регистрации - если будет слишком большой логин, рамка "уедет" ).

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы рамки не наезжали друг на друга, а сдвигались. Например, вправо.

[image]

Вот код страницы :

```
<!-- Верхняя строка -->
<div id="top_background">
<div id="top">
    <!-- Меню -->
    <ul id="menu">
            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
            var d=300;
            $('#menu a').each(function(){
                $(this).stop().animate({
                    'marginTop':'-80px'
                },d+=150);
            });

            $('#menu > li').hover(
            function () {
                $('a',$(this)).stop().animate({
                    'marginTop':'-2px'
                },200);
            },
            function () {
                $('a',$(this)).stop().animate({
                    'marginTop':'-80px'
                },200);
            }
        );
        }); 

    </script>
             {foreach $pages as $p}
            {* Выводим только страницы из первого меню *}
            {if $p->menu_id == 1}
            <li {if $page && $page->id == $p->id}class="selected"{/if}>
                <a data-page="{$p->id}" href="{$p->url}">{$p->name|escape}</a>
            </li>
            {/if}
        {/foreach}       
    </ul>
    <!-- Меню (The End) -->
    <!-- Корзина -->
    <div id="cart_informer">
        {* Обновляемая аяксом корзина должна быть в отдельном файле *}
        {include file='cart_informer.tpl'}
    </div>
    <!-- Корзина (The End)-->



    <!-- Вход пользователя -->
    <div id="account">
        {if $user}
            <span id="username">
                <a href="user">{$user->name}</a>{if      $group->discount>0},
                ваша скидка &mdash; {$group->discount}%{/if}
            </span>
            <a id="logout" href="user/logout">выйти</a>
        {else}
            <a id="register" href="user/register">Регистрация</a>
            <a id="login" href="user/login">Вход</a>
        {/if}
    </div>
    <!-- Вход пользователя (The End)-->



</div>
</div>
<!-- Верхняя строка (The End)-->
```

Это css:

```
#top {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 940px;
}
ul#menu {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    width: 721px;
    z-index: 999999;
}
ul#menu li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    width: 103px;
}
ul#menu li a {
    -khtml-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #e7f2f9;
    background-position: 50% 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 1px solid #3cf;
    display: block;
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity=70);
    float: left;
    height: 25px;
    margin-top: -2px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    padding-top: 80px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100px;
}
ul#menu li a:hover {
    background-color: #cae3f2;
}
ul#menu a:hover {
    background-image: url("../images/home.png");
}
ul#menu a[href^="blog"] {
    background-image: url("../images/id_card.png");
}
ul#menu a[href^="dostavka"] {
    background-image: url("../images/search.png");
}
ul#menu a[href^="oplata"] {
    background-image: url("../images/ipod.png");
}
ul#menu a[href^="contact"] {
    background-image: url("../images/rss.png");
}
#cart_informer {
    background-color: #e7f2f9;
    border: 1px solid #3cf;
    color: #3cf;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 515px;
    margin-top: -13px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    padding: 5px 13px 6px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 999999;
}
#account {
    background-color: #e7f2f9;
    border: 1px solid #3cf;
    color: #3cf;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: -13px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    padding: 5px 49px 6px 13px;
    position: inherit;
    z-index: 999999;
}
#account #login {
    padding-left: 7px;
}
#account #logout {
    padding-left: 7px;
}
```

Comment: Покажите код самого меню.

Comment: Перемудрили с fixed. Используйте для блоков "меню" и "корзины" float:left; а для блока регистрации float:right; и всё будет нормально двигаться. Только, потом не забудьте очистить float.

Comment: Только, потом не забудьте очистить float....-это как понимать?

Comment: >Только, потом не забудьте очистить float....-это как понимать?

clear: left; /* или right*/

Comment: то есть если я для корзины и меню добавил  float:left;...то мне там же нужно добавить clear: right...да?

Comment: Сделал все выше перечисленное-эффект тот же.либо наезжают друг например при увеличении строки с ценой....либо наоборот-между корзиной и авторизацией-Отверстие

Comment: @HoPkInS, сброс float делают для элементов, идущих за тем, на который этот флоат добавлен, чтобы снять влияние. Да и не всегда это нужно, всё по ситуации надо смотреть.

Не знаю, что вам подсказать, т.к. видеть в действии ваше творение не могу, а телепатические свойста у меня не развиты.

Comment: Только, потом не забудьте очистить float....-это как понимать?

clear:both для следующего после регистрации элемента или используйте класс clearfix для блока оборачивающего меню, корзину и регистрацию.